# how to Append result of $.Get to container inside the .Drop event in jquery droppable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, append

Inside the jquery Droppable I want to trigger .Drop event, and call Ajax Get, then append to container.

1. How can I use an Ajax $.`Get` inside Drop and then Append into the DropZoneContainer
2. reading other posts, I saw them remove CSS on the dropped elements (do, I need to, can you share why)
3. How can I make it sortable - clarification (the dropped elements, more specifically, the $.`Get` return's `Divs`, i.e. coming back from server, and into a 2 column grid and need to be able to sort across the 2 column grid.
4. Also, should I trigger this on `Drop` or on `Accept`
5. Do I need to stop / cancel default propagation of events after drop

> ```
> $("#DropZone1 #DropZone2").droppable({
>    drop: function(event, ui) {
>                    // do appending of server side div into the DropZone
>                    // where $(this).doSomething() - 
>                    // call ajax .get and append to 
>                    $(this)
>                     .append($.get("/some-url/" + $(ui.draggable).text(), function(response-data){ #my HTML fragment response-data }););  
>                    // do something with the draggable item
>                    //$(ui.draggable).doSomething();
>                }
>         });
> ```

Comment: Could you join this chat room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48748/room-for-rakhi4110-and-aroos

Answer (score 1):

To make an ajax request and append the response to the either a droppable / draggable container can be done by setting the context as shown below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#DropZone").droppable({
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/some-url/' + $(ui.draggable).text(),
                success: function(data, status, xhr){
                    $(this).append(data);
                },
                context: this //context:ui.draggable to append to draggable container
            });
        }
    });
});
```

This can be triggered on drop, as a drop is an **event** which would be triggered, only when an accepted draggable is dropped. On the other hand accept is an **option** used to control the kind of draggable elements that can be accepted. For more info on this refer [this](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#option-accept).

Comment: @aroos. Not required. The default is GET if nothing is specified.

Comment: I see, thx. The GET is expecting a HTML fragment response, which then needs to be inserted into the #DropZone. I threw up an alert when done, but the #dropZone didnt update with the fragement. So, I'm asking 1) if there needs to be another setting to show HTML response. 2) why are we passing XHR. 3) what is the context doing/setting when $(this).append is telling it where to put it.

Comment: join this chat room chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48748/room-for-rakhi4110-and-aroos so that we figure out your problem